# how to expand a div col in bootstrap on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using bootstrap to build a page. I have a section in which there is 6 different sections (3 in a row).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div style="background:#ababab">Lorium ispum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div style="background:#ababab">Lorium ispum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div style="background:#ababab">Lorium ispum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div style="background:#ababab">Lorium ispum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div style="background:#ababab">Lorium ispum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div style="background:#ababab">Lorium ispum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to expand a `col` to the full width of the container on mouse over. Meanwhile, the other `col` sections will be disappeared.

I tried to adapt to hide the all 5 cols on mouse over through jQuery. But don't know how to expand the container. Can anybody help me to solve this? If you need any help, just let me know.

Comment: Using jQuery just hide the DIVs change the hovered DIV's class to be col-md-12 rather than col-md-4. And on mouseout change the class back and show the hidden DIVs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9BLr3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's hover method:

```
$('.col-md-4').hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('col-md-4').addClass('col-md-12');
    $this.siblings('.col-md-4').hide();
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-4');
    $this.siblings('.col-md-4').show();
});
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k958H/

Comment: not just the siblings all other 5 elements has to be hidden

Comment: Here is a fiddle for hiding all the elements, but hiding elements across rows can be problematic because when hovering the second row you hide the first row causing the bottom row to move up and fire the mouse out event. http://jsfiddle.net/k958H/1/