# Responsive bootstrap rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I currently have the following 3 columns in a bootstrap row that are using, given they are md-4 they are taking up equal portions

Essentially it looks like:

ColA    ColB    ColC

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> <p class="control-label h3"> ColA </p>
        <div class="jumbotron ColA">
            <textarea class="tArea" id="AText" rows="5"></textarea>

        </div>

        <p class="control-label h3">ColB </p>
        <div class="jumbotron ColB">
            <textarea class="tArea" id="BText" rows="5" cols="25" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8"><p class="control-label h3">ColC </p>
        <div class="jumbotron ColC">
            <textarea class="tArea" id="CText" rows="5" cols="25" ></textarea>
        </div></div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to implement is an on hover of the column that expands it to twice the height and width while pushing or pulling the other columns to the left.

As an Example, if I hovered over Cola Id See the layout look like this:

|ColB  |ColA | 
|ColC  |MoreA|

hovering Over B would yeild:

|ColA |ColB | 
|ColC |MoreB|

And C:

|ColA |ColC | 
|ColB |MoreC|

I have tried pulling, pushing and floating the divs respectively and am able to get desired behaviour on A and B but it seems very inconstant and not something i could easily implement in Jquery. Is there some css property i am overlooking to help achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150690/how-to-expand-a-div-col-in-bootstrap-on-hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150690/how-to-expand-a-div-col-in-bootstrap-on-hover)

Comment: do any of the columns have fixed heights?

Comment: The issue you will run into is if you hover over `A`, it will shift and then the mouse will be hovered over `B`.

Comment: @SuperVeetz they are set, part of the hoover would be expanding them to cover twice as much.